# Configure WebSEAL Junction Mapping

Tags: junction-table, tivoli, webseal

Hi I am trying to configure my jmt.conf file.Though i write the junction name in it . When i try to load the table with server task command it gives me couldnot reach to server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was the problem with the permission of jmt .conf file

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create your junction map file, make sure the permissions are correct, then load the mappings.

1. Look in your config file (usually `webseald-default.conf`) and under the `[junction]` stanza look for the value for `jmt-map` (probably `lib/jmt.conf`)
2. Edit the file that is referred to in the `jmt-map` property (PS: it will be relative to your base WebSEAL directory) and add your mappings:

   `/junctionA /map/this/to/junctionA/*`

   `/junctionB /map/this/to/junctionB/index.html`
3. If you created the jmt.conf file, change the permissions on it to the user and group WebSEAL runs as.  Usually this is `ivmgr:ivmgr` and `chmod 0640`.  If you don't do this, WebSEAL won't be able to read it unless the other permissions are set to read (e.g. 644).  Even if you didn't create the file, check the permissions.
4. Issue, using pdadmin, the command `server task server-name jmt load` where your server-name is your WebSEAL server (find using `server list`).

That should be it.  Now going to `https://server.yourdomain.com/map/this/to/junctionA/whatever` will pull from `/junctionA/whatever`.

PS:  You might considering creating your junctions with the `-j` option to enable cookie junction mapping if you are having issues with your apps.  Junction mappings have their place, but I have seen them used when cookie mapping would have worked better, especially since cookie mappings are less maintenance in the long term.  You could also consider a virtualhost junction.  I had one application that needed so many mappings we ended up creating a virtualhost junction for them.  It ended up working out a lot better.  The only downside was we had to get an SSL cert for the subdomain.

Here are some references for WebSEAL v6.1.1 from the IBM InfoCenter site:

`server task jmt load command` - https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/tivihelp/v2r1/topic/com.ibm.itame.doc_6.1/am61_webseal_admin1388.htm?path=5_12_0_8_1_6_0_3_1_13_2_9#servertaskjmtcli

Using junction mapping - https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/tivihelp/v2r1/topic/com.ibm.itame.doc_6.1/am61_webseal_admin583.htm?path=5_12_0_8_1_6_0_3_1_8_2_3_0#junction-mapping